# Quotient norm for a subspace of $C[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, quotient-spaces

Let $C[0,1]$ be the space of all continuous real valued functions defined on $[0,1]$ and let $Y$ be the closed subspace of $C[0,1]$ consisting of constant functions. Then I am asked to explicitly compute the quotient norm for any function(coset representative) of the quotient space $C[0,1]/Y$ .

Quotient norm:- If $q$ is the quotient map then $||q(x)||=\inf_{y\in Y} ||x-y||= d(x,Y)$

**My attempt:-**

What we want is $\displaystyle d(f,Y)=\inf_{c\in Y}\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)-c|$ . Now as $f$ attains it's maximum and minimum for some points $x_{min}$ and $x_{max}$ in $[0,1]$ . After drawing a few graphs I was able to see that

$$\sup|f(x)-c| = \begin{cases} |c-f(x_{min})|\,, c\geq \frac{f(x_{max})+f(x_{min})}{2}\\ |c-f(x_{max})|\,,c\leq\frac{f(x_{min})+f(x_{max})}{2}\end{cases} $$

Therefore I conclude that $d(f,Y)=\frac{|f(x_{max})-f(x_{min})|}{2}$ . It matches with the fact that if $d(f,Y)=0$ then $f(x_{max})=f(x_{min})\implies$ f is a constant.

I am however not hundred percent sure of it's rigor or if I am missing some big detail. Can anyone please comment on my attempt and guide me to the correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is correct, and your approach is great. However, after finding the solution you should find a rigorous explanation and this is what is missing.

- For any $c\in\Bbb R$ we have
  $$
  \|f-c\|_\infty\geq |f(x_{\mathrm{max}})-c|
  \text{ and } 
  \|f-c\|_\infty\geq |f(x_{\mathrm{min}})-c|
  $$
  so
  $$
  2\|f-c\|_\infty\geq |f(x_{\mathrm{max}})-c|+|f(x_{\mathrm{min}})-c| \geq
  |f(x_{\mathrm{min}})-f(x_{\mathrm{min}})|.
  $$
  This shows that $\|f-c\|_\infty\geq \frac 12|f(x_{\mathrm{min}})-f(x_{\mathrm{min}})| =:A$ and therefore $d(f,Y)\geq A$.
- On the other hand, taking $c=\frac 12\left(f(x_{\mathrm{min}})+f(x_{\mathrm{min}}\right)$ we get
  $f(x)\in [f(x_{\mathrm{min}}),c]\cup[c,f(x_{\mathrm{max}})]$ (two segments of tte length $A$) so $|f(x)-c|\leq A$. This implies that $\|f-a\|_\infty\leq A$ and  therefore
  $d(f,Y)\leq A$.

Comment: Perfectly explained. I was relying more on a graphical intuition . However can I just ask you one thing? . I explicitly calculated the infimum and I don't understand why that could be considered as less rigorous

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to say that I should have added a more elaborate justification as to why it is the infimum?

Comment: @Dovahkiin, as you've written, you used the proof by graph: ' After drawing a few graphs I was able to see that'. This is a not so precise part.